# Newton's method for implicit Runge Kutta methods

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Runge Kutta methods for the ODE $y'=f(y)$ are defined by the stages $k_i$, $i=1\dots s$:
$$k_i=f\left(y_0+\sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij} \, k_j\right)$$
and then the time advance:
$$y_1=y_0+h \sum_{j=1}^s b_i \, k_i $$
(I assume no time dependence in the ODE just to avoid clattering notation).

Some books/papers use a different notation, e.g. $g_i$, with $k_i=f(g_i)$. No problem with that (admittedly, after some confusion) and rewriting the defining equations is almost copy/paste:
$$g_i= y_0+\sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij} \, f(g_j) $$
$$y_1=y_0+h \sum_{j=1}^s b_i \, f(g_i) $$
For explicit methods, choosing one set of equations is just a matter of defining different variables in the code and storing results either after or before applying the function $f$.

However, suppose we want to use implicit methods, solving the system of $n\cdot s$ algebraic equations with exact Newton's method until convergence. Each set of equations leads to a different system, so my question is: is there an established choice?, should I solve for the $k$-stages or for the $g$-stages?

I have been unable to find any hint in the literature... maybe simply no one bothers nowadays to implement fully implicit methods and alternatives such as Rosenbrock and SDIRK methods are pursued? :)

Comment: The two systems (either solving for $k_i$ or solving for $g_i$) are equivalent as long as the equation system has a solution so I do not see why it should matter which system you solve.

Comment: @Winther The equivalence is clear for the *system* itself, but not so for the Newton solution, which is sometimes fussy about the initial value.

Comment: The assumption one has to make here is that the Newton system converges (and likely that the solution for $k_i$ or $f(g_i)$ is the unique). For cases where it does not converge then then this method simply breaks down.

Comment: @Winther Consider the equation $x=e^{x-3}$, easily solved by Newton with $x_0=1$. Now change the variable to $x=e^y$ obtaining $y=e^y-3$ with $y_0=0$ that fails at the first step. It is a contrived example, yes, but it shows that at least some care must be exercised...